# How to use array `env` resolver in configuration?

Tags: symfony, configuration, yaml, symfony4

I'm trying to set the parameter `ips` for access control in Symfony by using the `.env` files. I'm using `4.2.4`.

This is an excerpt of my configuration:

```
security:
     access_control:
         -
             ips: '%env(csv:VAR)%'
```

This is an excerpt of my environment variables:

```
VAR=172.16.0.0/12,127.0.0.1
```

And this is the exception:

> InvalidTypeException
>
> Invalid type for path "security.access_control.0.ips.0". Expected one of "bool", "int", "float", "string", but got "array".

I understand that `...ips.0` is an element of `ips` and thus it has not to be an `array`. But I don't understand why it tries to assign the whole array not to `ips`. What's my mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the security bundle wraps strings in an array, see [here](https://github.com/symfony/security-bundle/blob/00b4f06d6522d7d6c3eb625e8aba545d04d33c0d/DependencyInjection/MainConfiguration.php#L145). When you change that you will end in issues like [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28137). So at the moment it seems there is no possibility to get that.